# How to retrieve dataset from SQL query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I am trying to retrieve `Dataset` from a SQL query. I am using Edmx for data access. If I use one simple stored procedure for retrieving dataTable then the function works fine and when I am trying to retrieve Dataset then I am unable to convert the SQL result to a dataset.

Here is my Sql

```
--Query For Retrieving LastUpdatedDate
select top 3 
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessID,
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessName,
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.LastUpdatedByDate as GeneraliseDate
from  
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys
order by  
    GeneraliseDate desc

--Query For Retrieving Listing by CreatedDate
select top 3 
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessID,
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessName,
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.CreatedByDate as GeneraliseDate
from  
    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys
order by  
    GeneraliseDate desc
```

How can I retrieve dataset in SQl result in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given sql query, the simplest way to populate result into dataset is the using of [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) class, which does all the job(you only need to provide query and opened connection, and dataset to fill).

In you case it would be:

```
string queryString1 = "select top 3 YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessID,
                                    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessName,
                                    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.LastUpdatedByDate as GeneraliseDate
                       from  YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys
                       order by  GeneraliseDate desc"

string queryString2 = "select top 3 YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessID,
                                    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessName,
                                    YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.CreatedByDate as GeneraliseDate
                        from  YP.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys
                        order by  GeneraliseDate desc"

string queryString = queryString1 + Environment.NewLine + queryString2;


DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

var connection = new SqlConnection("TODO:put connection string here");
connection.Open();
using(connection)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection); 
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
}

// here you go
foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(table.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework returns entities and not datatable or dataset. 
you can use ADO.net (SqlCommand , SqlAdapter , .... ) 
or do it manually by using .AsEnumerable() and fill it in a new datatable or dataset !